# Subir multiples imagenes AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, imagen, upload

Que tal, les pido su ayuda, quiero seleccionar imagenes en una sola carga, es decir que el usuario elija si quiere subir una sola imagen o mas de una.
Lo estoy realizando de las siguiente manera:

```js
app.controller('ImagesCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout, $location, $window, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    'use strict';
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    const REF = firebase.database().ref();

    
        $scope.thumbnail = {
        dataUrl: 'adsfas'
    };
    $scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
    $scope.photoChanged = function(files){ 
        if (files != null) {
            for(let i=0; i>files.length; i++){
            let file = files[i];
            if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    let fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    fileReader.onload = function(e) {
                        $timeout(function(){
                            $scope.thumbnail.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                            console.log(e.target.result);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        }
    };

});
});
```

```html
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)" multiple/>
        <img ng-src="{{ thumbnail.dataUrl }}"/>
```

El problema es que solo me trae la primer imagen que selecciono, estoy intentando pasaras a un arreglo para después guardarlas en firebase. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estas limitando tu programa a hacer eso exactamente justo en donde escribes: `let file = files[0];`. De todos los archivos que seleccionaste, solamente estas procesando el primero.

Comment: Hice un for pero ahora no me manda las imagenes, sabras el por qué? gracias por tu ayuda!! actualice la pregunta con lo que le agregue

Comment: Debes tener mas cuidado. Dentro del for tienes: for(let i=0; i>files.length; i++) cuando deberia ser for(let i=0; i<files.length; i++). Realmente el for que tienes implementado nunca se esta ejecutando.